# How to force an action to be performed on a component?

Tags: java, swing, events, listeners

I have a textbox and a button in a swing form with other components. My text box is registered with focus listener and button is registered with action listener.

If i change text in text box and without losing the focus, click on the button, my focus listener gets executed and button's action listener is never executed.

Is there way to forcefully (programmatically) invoke the action listener on the button after focus Listener on textbox done its part?

Comment: In order to get help try to provide a [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: _without losing the focus, click on the button_ that's a contradiction in itself (as the focusListener tells you :-) _button's action listener is never executed_ that's strange, most probably something wrong in the code you are not showing. So best to follow @Howard's advice to get better help sooner.

Comment: I think as long as keyboard cursor is in text box, it doesn't loose focus and i can always use mouse to click on the button, but as soon as i click the button, focus listener is in charge and focusLost of text fields is executed. My problem is that button click event is not fired in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `yourButton.doClick();` ?

Comment: while technically possible, unlikely to _really_ solve the OP's problem (which sounds a bit weird :-)